# how to deal with responses containing unicode in Kitura (swift)

Tags: swift, rest, get, codable, kitura

I have a route ("/states"):

```swift
func initializeCodableRoutes(app: App) {
    app.router.get("/states", handler: app.getStatesHandler)
}
```

here is the corresponding handler (Codable handler):

```swift
extension App {
    func getStatesHandler(completion: ([State], RequestError?) -> Void) {
        let result = [State(id: 1, name: "تهران"),
                      State(id: 2, name: "آذربایجان شرقی"),
                      State(id: 3, name: "کرمان"),
                      State(id: 4, name: "آذربایجان غربی"),
                      State(id: 5, name: "اردبیل"),
                      State(id: 6, name: "اصفهان"),
                      State(id: 7, name: "البرز"),
                      State(id: 8, name: "ایلام"),
                      State(id: 9, name: "بوشهر"),
                      State(id: 10, name: "چهارمحال و بختیاری"),
                      State(id: 11, name: "خراسان جنوبی"),
                      State(id: 12, name: "خراسان رضوی")]
        completion(result, nil)
    }
}
```

and this is the code of State struct for more clarity:

```swift
struct State: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}
```

when I run my server and try the {baseurl}/states in the browser, I get response like this:

```json
[{"id":1,"name":"ØªÙ‡Ø±Ø§Ù†"},{"id":2,"name":"Ø¢Ø°Ø±Ø¨Ø§ÛŒØ¬Ø§Ù† Ø´Ø±Ù‚ÛŒ"},{"id":3,"name":"Ú©Ø±Ù…Ø§Ù†"},{"id":4,"name":"Ø¢Ø°Ø±Ø¨Ø§ÛŒØ¬Ø§Ù† ØºØ±Ø¨ÛŒ"},{"id":5,"name":"Ø§Ø±Ø¯Ø¨ÛŒÙ„"},{"id":6,"name":"Ø§ØµÙÙ‡Ø§Ù†"},{"id":7,"name":"Ø§Ù„Ø¨Ø±Ø²"},{"id":8,"name":"Ø§ÛŒÙ„Ø§Ù…"},{"id":9,"name":"Ø¨ÙˆØ´Ù‡Ø±"},{"id":10,"name":"Ú†Ù‡Ø§Ø±Ù…Ø­Ø§Ù„ Ùˆ Ø¨Ø®ØªÛŒØ§Ø±ÛŒ"},{"id":11,"name":"Ø®Ø±Ø§Ø³Ø§Ù† Ø¬Ù†ÙˆØ¨ÛŒ"},{"id":12,"name":"Ø®Ø±Ø§Ø³Ø§Ù† Ø±Ø¶ÙˆÛŒ"},{"id":13,"name":"Test"},{"id":14,"name":"ØªØ³Øª"}]
```

how can I get the correct unicode response?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure, but this may shed some light on your issue. https://forums.swift.org/t/why-is-character-not-codable/56178/15

Comment: how did you turn the response to a  json`String` and printed it? Note, `State` is already a Swift word, it is best to use another name for your own struct, it may/will confuse you and the compiler eventually.

Comment: Looks like you are decoding the data you get into `ascii`.
Use `utf8` instead, to get the original (json) data string representation.

Answer (score 0):

I tried several browsers and saw that for example, firefox shows the correct unicode response(while safari not), so I understood that the problem sits in the decoding side of the client. server-side code works good enough.